# How to use an AS3 timer to execute and loop movie clips of different length?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, timer, movieclip, countdown

How would I go about using a timer to initiate multiple movie clips at once, and then loop them if they are all different lengths so that they restart in sync once more?

For example, say at t=0, 3 movie clips are started. Movie clip 1 is 3 seconds long. Movie clip 2 is 6 seconds long. Movie clip 3 is 10 seconds long. Movie clip 1 would end before movie clip 2 and 3, but I don't want it to restart until the others are both finished.

Furthermore, is it possible to set a countdown so that the the movie clips are initiated not after a duration, but after a specific time? For example, instead of having a timer countdown from 10 seconds and then playing, it instead countdowns until say 12:00 PM and then plays the movie clip. If this is possible, can anyone show me how?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would go about your first question - just add all of your animating MovieClips to the `mcs` array.

```
var mcs:Array = [mc1,mc2,mc3];

// work out the longest running MovieClip
var longest:MovieClip = mcs[0];

var i:MovieClip;
for each(i in mcs)
{
    if(i.totalFrames > longest.totalFrames) longest = i;

    i.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME, animation);
}

/**
 * Check animation progress on each MovieClip
 */
function animation(e:Event):void
{
    var m:MovieClip = MovieClip(e.target);

    if(m.currentFrame == m.totalFrames)
    {
        m.stop();

        if(m == longest)
        {
            var i:MovieClip;
            for each(i in mcs)
            {
                i.gotoAndPlay(1);

                // your own actions here
                // for when all animation completes
            }
        }
    }
}
```

As for the latter question, I'm not sure why you would want to do this, but here's a simple enough approach:

```
var d:Date = new Date();
var time:String = d.getHours() + ":" + d.getMinutes();

var ran:Boolean = false;
if(time == "12:00" && !ran)
{
    ran = true;
    // being your animations etc
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for the longest clip :

```
longestClip.addFrameScript(longestClip.totalFrames, restartAllMyClips);
```

restartAllMyClips being a function that will restart them all.

Make sense ?

For the time issue -- you can have that code above call a function called waitAndPlay(time)

basically in that function you could calculate the amount of time between that moment and the time you pass as a parameter.

Then you just set a Timer for that duration. Set a listener on that timer to execute restartAllMyClips.

so something like this :

```
var waitTimer:Timer = new Timer(duration, 1);
waitTimer.addEventListener(TimerEvent.TIMER_COMPLETE, restartAllMyClips);
waitTimer.start();
```

Here's some info on addFrameScript() -- http://blog.rackdoll.nl/?p=118

Comment: What is **addFrameScript()**?

Comment: it's voodoo :) A undocumented function, you don't see it much. But it works perfect for a situation like this!